# How to install FreeMind (free mind mapping software) on Ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: software-installation

How to install FreeMind (free mind mapping software) in Ubuntu 16.4 with command line ?

Comment: They do not support 16.04, here is their download page with apt link  http://www.getdeb.net/app/Freemind but it only supports 14.xx and 15.xx

Comment: The latest version on ppa is for... Jaunty. The latest edit here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/freemind/files/freemind-deb/0.8.1/ is from 2008, of which you may conclude that the Freemind project is completely dead.

Comment: @MarkKirby , Thank you so much, I need to install best mind mapping software for ubuntu 16.04, Which software installed?

Comment: @JacobVlijm , Thank you so much, Which software installed in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I am using Xmind, but it is commercial, so it can be frowned uppon to suggest. The free version (which I use) has some limitations.

Comment: Although the dupe- question is not literally what you asked for,  I believe that is what answers this question in the best possible way. Some of the suggestions aren't valid anymore, some are.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Thanks, I download Xmind and how to install XMind on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: ...extract the downloaded `.zip` file, then run `setup.sh` inside the extracted folder.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Thank you so much, in terminal ./setup.sh :-) please answer this question and like your help

Comment: Hi @Shayvard I am glad it works, and you're welcome! This question will most likely be duped to the linked one, which is useful to show others, looking for the same, the way to those answers. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Thank you for helping me, I install Xmind, but how to run xmind ?

Comment: It should be visible in Dash, possibly you'll have to log out/in. I have to run, will be back! Wait, I don't see a .desktop file in v.8? I use 7. I will find out! Maybe the question should be: *"How to install Xmind 8"* ...to be continued, Tonight I will uninstall 7, install 8 to find out.

Comment: Hi @Shayvard, Xmind used to come in a .deb file, but obviously not anymore. V. 8 can be used however. Could you Ask a new question: "How to install & run Xmind v. 8?" I will answer then. Could you ping me if you do?  I have an answer written and ready to post.

Comment: Hi @JacobVlijm , I create a new question, please answer then. :-)

Comment: Hi Shayvardposted, but @Rinzwind's answer might be more convenient :)

Comment: @Shayvard don't mention it, you're welcome!

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/freemind/discussion/22102/thread/33f5ff09/                Go through this link, you will find very nice answer.